# Read Information of the Device Manager with Java

Tags: java, windows, device-manager

I would like to know how to read out the information which can be found in the Device Manager with Java. I've found  JNA (Java Native Access) and Java Communications API (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) but I can't find if this is what I need.

I have a specific Bus (under System Devices) and want to read some of the information/properties of this device. This should be able with PC/SC Api.

Could anybody help?